# Detect that Windows Phone Scrollviewer has reached full scroll extent

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have windows phone app that has a Scrollviewer listing some content retrieved online.

I am trying to find a way to trigger a refresh when the scroll position has reached it's maximum scroll extent.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into the MouseMove event of the ScrollViewer control, then if the VerticalOffset value equals the ScrollableHeight value then you know you need to load more content.

Comment: Yeah, and problem that - scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, doesn't always work. Sometimes VerticalOffset is smaller than ScrollableHeight, even if end is reached.